# Split string help! Splitting a file by certain characters but ignoring strings in quotes in java with regex

Tags: java, regex, string, split

for example I have a file like this:

```
INT f2(INT x, INT y ) 
  BEGIN 
  z := x*x - y*y;
RETURN z; 
END 
INT MAIN f1() 
BEGIN
  INT x;
  READ(x, "A41.input");
  INT y;
  READ(y, "A42.input");
  INT z;
  z := f2(x,y) + f2(y,x);
  WRITE (z, "A4.output");

END
```

I open the file using:

```
 FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("A1input.txt");
 DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
 String strLine;
```

and then in order to split each line by characters like ; or = i did this:

```
String[] SplitString = strLine.split("[\\s\\W]");
```

I was wondering if there was a way to delete the words in between quotes (eg. "A41.input") using regex so I can ignore those words all together before doing the split

Comment: the main goal of the program Im writing is to count the identifiers in a file using regex

Comment: Yes you can use `strlLine.replaceAll("regex pattern","")` to remove the words inside quotes. GoodLuck with that regex pattern.

Comment: this might sound dumb, but what goes in the place of regex pattern in your solution?

Comment: that you have to figure out. take a look here http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Comment: Are you still stuck with this?

Answer (score 0):

Because it's still open, two possibilities (out of many)

`"\b.*?\b\W*\b.*?\b"`

or

`".*?"`

Escaping backslashes and double quotes in java:

```
    String str = "READ(y, \"A42.input\");";
    System.out.println(str);
    String replacedFirst = str.replaceAll("\".*?\"", "\"\"");
    String replacedSecond = str.replaceAll("\"\\b.*?\\b\\W*\\b.*?\\b\"","\"\"");
    System.out.println(replacedFirst);
    System.out.println(replacedSecond);
```